# How to solve HTTP 403 error on input of data in Django Ajax?

Tags: django, ajax, http-status-code-403

I am trying to implement a search function to search for users of my blog. In my base.html I have my navbar and within the navbar I have the following search form:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="POST">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
        </div>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input id="user_search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
        <ul class="list-group" id="results"></ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

My ajax code looks as follows:

```
$('#user_search').keyup(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "{% url 'user-search' %}",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response){
                        $('#results').html(response['form']);
                        console.log($('.profile-section').html(response['form']));
                    },
                    error: function(rs, e){
                        console.log(rs.responseText);
                    },
                });
            });
```

and my `views.py` search view looks as follows:

```
def user_search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_text = request.POST['search_text']
    else:
        search_text = ''

    users = User.objects.filter(username__icontains=search_text)

    context = {
        'users': users,
    }

    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('feed/user_search.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

and the relevant part of my `urls.py` looks like this:

```
path('search/', login_required(views.user_search), name="user-search"),
```

When entering data in the input field I am getting a 403 HTTP error that says I am not using the csrf_token correctly, however I have included it as I did it before and it worked the other times before...
Any idea how I can solve the 403 error?

Comment: Add csrf token or exempt csrf token.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Should I remove the csrf_token from my html? Or where should I add another one because I already have a csrf_token in my form

Comment: check data that's being sent to the backend, check if that's csrf token. Not then you have to update ajax request data to consider csrf_token.

Comment: I have checked the data and a token is sent to the backend, in my console it says: `Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /feed/search/` so I assume the csrf token must be incorrect. How can I correct it?

Comment: Okay I fixed this and it works now! I had to change the ajax code a bit^^. Now I have another issue: It shows up all users if the input field is empty and then on input narrows down the results. How can I change the results to just display something if something is typed in?

Comment: On keyup event check the length of the query, if it's less than the minimum required length(e.g 3) then do not query backend. Also you might have to clear the display incase length becomes < required lenght.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the JS part like this:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.user-search-form', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var input = $('#user_search').val();
                console.log(input);
                if (input.length > 2) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: $(this).attr('action'),
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(response){
                            $('#results').html(response['form']);
                            console.log($('#results').html(response['form']));
                        },
                        error: function(rs, e){
                            console.log(rs.responseText);
                        },
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $('#results').empty();
                }
            });
```

and the python part in the `views.py` like that:

```
def user_search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_text = request.POST.get('input')

        users = User.objects.filter(username__icontains=search_text)
        context = {
            'users': users,
            }


    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('feed/user_search.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

and now the search works!